# Rmarkdown (html): create text/ commentary box on the html for user

Tags: html, r, text, r-markdown, box

I was wondering if I could create a floating/static text box on the html so that the user that browse my offline html page can jot some notes inside the box.

Comment: There are libraries such as shiny to create all kinds of interactive pages rendered from Rmarkdown.

Comment: thanks ferrix. do you know which widget from shiny could do the commentary?